# Create Thread on Class Method

Tags: python, multithreading, oop

How can I call thread on a class method passing it 'self'? I have a class defined as follows and want to call class method in new thread with self as argument. I tried following but self is not passed as argument

```
cust_obj = Customer()
thread.start_new_thread(cust_obj.process, ())  

class Customer():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def process(self):
        self.fetch_data()
        self.serialize_data()
    def fetch_data(self):
        # Fetch data logic
        pass
    def serialize_data(self):
        # Serialize fetched data
        pass
```

Comment: Ought to work (keyword: bound method). What's the error message?

Comment: That ought to work. Anyway, a simple workaround could be: `thread.start_new_thread((lambda: Customer().process()), ())`

Comment: Can't give any assistance until you state what fails.

Comment: unrelated to your current issue but you should use `threading` module instead of obsolete `thread`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should put the class definition before the instance creating. Then it will work.

```
class Customer():
    ...
cust_obj = Customer()
thread.start_new_thread(cust_obj.process, ())
```